# While testing angular code, how do I mock large parameters of functions?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I have ts functions which take parameters of specific interface types. In some scenarios those interfaces are very large, 30-40 lines.
So while testing this function, I have to pass it the argument as an object of this interface. But every time I have changes in the interface, I have to change these stubs. Is there a way to mock this parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I use the  `as any` typecast to help me in this scenario.

```
interface Person {
  name: string;
  height: number;
  age: number;
}

class Logger {
  logNameIfAndy(person: Person) {
    if (person.name === 'Andy') {
       console.log('Your name is Andy.');
    } else {
       console.log('Your name is not Andy.');
    }
  }
}
```

Then in a test, I don't have to mock out the height or age, just the properties I need.

```
const logger = new Logger();
// add the as any here to mock out only what is required and force it to be a
// Person type
logger.logNameIfAndy({ name: 'Andy' } as any);
```